# Updated version of @polkadot/api throws uncaught node error

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot

Upgraded @polkadot/api from version 6 to version 9

Uncaught NodeError Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './cjs/packageInfo' is not defined by "exports" in node_modules/@polkadot/networks/package.json

```
{
  "_from": "@polkadot/networks@10.2.1",
  "_id": "@polkadot/networks@10.2.1",
  "_inBundle": false,
  "_integrity": "sha512-cDZIY4jBo2tlDdSXNbECpuWer0NWlPcJNhHHveTiu2idje2QyIBNxBlAPViNGpz+ScAR0EknEzmQKuHOcSKxzg==",
  "_location": "/@polkadot/networks",
  "_phantomChildren": {},
  "_requested": {
    "type": "version",
    "registry": true,
    "raw": "@polkadot/networks@10.2.1",
    "name": "@polkadot/networks",
    "escapedName": "@polkadot%2fnetworks",
    "scope": "@polkadot",
    "rawSpec": "10.2.1",
    "saveSpec": null,
    "fetchSpec": "10.2.1"
  },
  "_requiredBy": [
    "/@polkadot/types-known",
    "/@polkadot/util-crypto"
  ],
  "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@polkadot/networks/-/networks-10.2.1.tgz",
  "_shasum": "5095011795afa20291ef3e34a2ad38ed2c63fe09",
  "_spec": "@polkadot/networks@10.2.1",
  "_where": "/home/charvik/codes/lcx-wallets-v2/node_modules/@polkadot/util-crypto",
  "author": {
    "name": "Jaco Greeff",
    "email": "jacogr@gmail.com"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/polkadot-js/common/issues"
  },
  "bundleDependencies": false,
  "contributors": [],
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.6",
    "@polkadot/util": "10.2.1",
    "@substrate/ss58-registry": "^1.35.0"
  },
  "deprecated": false,
  "description": "A list of all available Substrate networks and their applicable prefixes",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.0.0"
  },
  "exports": {
    "./cjs/package.json": "./cjs/package.json",
    "./cjs/*": "./cjs/*.js",
    ".": {
      "types": "./index.d.ts",
      "require": "./cjs/index.js",
      "default": "./index.js"
    },
    "./defaults": {
      "types": "./defaults/index.d.ts",
      "require": "./cjs/defaults/index.js",
      "default": "./defaults/index.js"
    },
    "./defaults/genesis": {
      "types": "./defaults/genesis.d.ts",
      "require": "./cjs/defaults/genesis.js",
      "default": "./defaults/genesis.js"
    },
    "./defaults/icons": {
      "types": "./defaults/icons.d.ts",
      "require": "./cjs/defaults/icons.js",
      "default": "./defaults/icons.js"
    },
    "./defaults/ledger": {
      "types": "./defaults/ledger.d.ts",
      "require": "./cjs/defaults/ledger.js",
      "default": "./defaults/ledger.js"
    },
    "./defaults/testnets": {
      "types": "./defaults/testnets.d.ts",
      "require": "./cjs/defaults/testnets.js",
      "default": "./defaults/testnets.js"
    },
    "./detectOther": {
      "types": "./detectOther.d.ts",
      "require": "./cjs/detectOther.js",
      "default": "./detectOther.js"
    },
    "./detectPackage": {
      "types": "./detectPackage.d.ts",
      "require": "./cjs/detectPackage.js",
      "default": "./detectPackage.js"
    },
    "./interfaces": {
      "types": "./interfaces.d.ts",
      "require": "./cjs/interfaces.js",
      "default": "./interfaces.js"
    },
    "./package.json": "./package.json",
    "./packageInfo.js": {
      "types": "./packageInfo.d.ts",
      "require": "./cjs/packageInfo.js",
      "default": "./packageInfo.js"
    },
    "./packageInfo": {
      "types": "./packageInfo.d.ts",
      "require": "./cjs/packageInfo.js",
      "default": "./packageInfo.js"
    },
    "./types": {
      "types": "./types.d.ts",
      "require": "./cjs/types.js",
      "default": "./types.js"
    }
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/polkadot-js/common/tree/master/packages/networks#readme",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "main": "./cjs/index.js",
  "maintainers": [],
  "module": "./index.js",
  "name": "@polkadot/networks",
  "repository": {
    "directory": "packages/networks",
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/polkadot-js/common.git"
  },
  "sideEffects": false,
  "type": "module",
  "types": "./index.d.ts",
  "version": "10.2.1"
}
```

Comment: Please add more detailed issue, ex: your package.json, your code that made errors.

Comment: @CocDap updated the question